# How to capture LTTng with all currently ubuntu running users

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, trace, lttng

I am checking the performance of RabbitMQ. I wrote a python program that create a few processes with pub-sub. I wish to do profiling on the system to see what its total message output and max frequency.

I used LTTng with combined trace-compass to view the output. I used LTTng to trace the kernel. This are the lttng commands I've used to capture data.

```
sudo lttng create -o ~/lttng_test session_test
sudo lttng enable-event session_test -k -a -c channel_test
sudo lttng start

sudo lttng stop
sudo lttng destroy
```

I was able to view all the processes my program created and analyze the data. But my results seems inconclusive. Sometime my python processes were [waiting for cpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RYyh.jpg) (marked in orange) which indicate they are doing actual work. Sometimes they seems to [wait blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGv43.jpg) (marked in yellow) , so they are waiting for event and not doing any work.

When processing the data via trace-compass I couldn't find the RabbitMQ processes which could explain some of the results. I've notice they are running from a user called rabbitmq.

My machine is running ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Can you provide the exact list of `lttng` commands you're using? Also, what are you expecting from the RabbitMQ processes in the trace? What do you mean by "LTTng did not show"? LTTng does not _show_ anything: the trace consumers (Babeltrace, Trace Compass) do.

Comment: I've edited my question accordingly